# What is happening? I/O error, dev sda, sector 545868115

Tags: external-hdd, sync

Since a few days ago, my computer freezes whenever I sync my HDD with an external USB3 drive. When the keyboard gets temporarily a bit responsive I am able to switch to another terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and I see the following image repeating continuously. I am on Ubuntu 11 using LuckyBackup.

What is going on? Is my hdd defective? Is it the external one? Something else?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'd bet that your hard disk is failing. Use the Disk Utility to verity it's smart status.

Comment: @JavierRivera Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to check and see if your disks are indeed failing. There are command line tools for monitoring SMART data (which is data that the hd reports about it's own health).

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools gsmartcontrol
```

Gsmartcontrol is a gui version of the same tool, and is very easy to use. Select the disk and run a short or long test in addition to viewing any errors the hd is reporting.

To run via the the command line, do the following

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda
```

Make sure SMART is turned on. If not,

```
sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda
```

Finally, run

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

or if it's a serial ata drive.

```
sudo smartctl -a -d ata /dev/sda
```

See this link for more info about smartmontools.
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/TocDoc

Comment: Indeed, my hard drive failed beyond repair a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your HDD definitely looks like its reaching **(EOL)**, End of Life. To elaborate on Javier's comment, I would suggest using an **Ubuntu Live CD** as opposed to the Disk Utility within your current Ubuntu instance, (for the obvious reason that when you plug in your external HDD the OS becomes unusable), and run the following command from the command line to check for disk errors:

```
e2fsck -f -c -v /dev/sdX
```

Where ***sdX*** is the mount point of your external HDD. The external HDD should be plugged in but **not mounted**, you can unmount the disk using the Disk Utility, and as Javier pointed out you can also use the Disk Utility to check the ***SMART*** status of the HDD if it is SMART capable/ enabled.

Again, do all of this from within the Ubuntu LiveCD. While you are at it, check for errors/ health of your primary HDD.

Comment: Sorry. The OS becomes unusable only when I synchronize primary disk w/ external HDD. From the attached image, how do you tell it's the external HDD failing (2months old) and not the primary disk (1yr old)?

Comment: You can see "dev sda" in there - sda is the first hard disk attached to the system, so it does look like your internal one to me.

Comment: It was an assumption made without knowing your current setup, but as Caesium pointed out /dev/sda is the first disk attached to your system so it could very well be that one. You are putting the disk under more stress than it's used to when you 'sync' it with your external HDD and that is probably why it only seems to be failing then. I would follow the steps I outlined above to check the health of both disks anyway, if you find that your primary disk is failing you will need to backup your important data in a less stressful manor before it fails for good.

Comment: sda is the first *detected* disk; that very well could be the external one.

Comment: mine can't be detected using` sudo fdisk -l` is my hdd dead

Comment: @Boris Is it an external or internal HDD?

Comment: It is External hdd

Comment: USB? If so check the output of `dmesg` when you plug it in to see that your OS recognizes it and that it gets power. You also need to see how it's formatted, if it's formatted with NTFS and depending on your OS you might have to load additional software and run specific commands to correctly mount it.