# What mount point should I use?

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, live-usb, grubrescue

I just installed Ubuntu twice and I get a GRUB Error.

I think it's because of the mount point. Since I put it at the root of the HDD. Where do I put it?

Is it `/` or `/boot`? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: What GRUB error are you getting? Take a look at this post that may be useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Attempt to read or write outside of (hd0) Grub Rescue> Or something like that

Comment: Also I don't have windows on the computer

Comment: Did you make a "/boot" and a "/" root partitions or just the "/boot" ?

Comment: No i made just the "/" thinking it was just an error.

Comment: @TylerBrown Have you tried with the methods mentioned in the link that I give you? Also, see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/229715/62483), I think that you have exactly the same problem, isn't?

Answer (score 4):

Your boot loader will install on /boot partition.  For mount point you must use `/`.  Plus
if you only have one partition, then it has to be root 
`/`.

`/` The root (`/`) partition stores the core system files and remain relatively fixed. Being separate from everything else should give it extra security.