# error: no such partition Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

I am using Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10 as in dual boot. I have changed my disk size using disk management in Windows 8.1-- specifically I have clubbed another partition into local disc C in Windows. I haven't touched  Ubuntu partition at all. Once I restarted the system, I am getting

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I tried methods mentioned in different forms like Ubuntu live USB, placing windows CD in optical drive, nothing is happening. just getting the error message. I tried to use F11 button but nothing happens.

Is there anything I can do to solve the problem?

I am not much of software techie, but I can follow steps to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: You can try the solution given in the following link:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error/397520#397520

Comment: not working. i am unable to get any page displayed after lenovo logo other than error: no such partition msg

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have ubuntu live cd, boot from cd and click try ubuntu
2. Then find terminal window
3. Type `sudo apt-get install lilo` and `then sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr` (you should have      internet connection to perform this) then restart
4. If you do not have internet follow this on latest ubuntu live cd's  `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`

Comment: geting error, Fatal: read /dev/sda: No such file or directory