# Ubuntu 13.04 is showing some error while opening my computer

Tags: boot, 13.04

Few months before when I was using Ubuntu 12.04 then I found some errors while starting my computer.

Due to this problem I had given my CPU to a shop to repair it **I don't know what he has done to my CPU but I only know that finally I got my CPU with Ubuntu 13.04.**

The technician was unable to make any partition and I also think that **he had installed 13.04 over 12.04** and so now my computer is showing some error when I'm starting my computer the error is as follows:

> error: attempt to read or write outside of the disk 'hd0'.
>
> grub rescue > _

Before showing this error, few times my computer was working very slow.

So kindly someone tell me that is there any way by which I can start my computer.

Please also tell me that what things I have to keep in mind while using Ubuntu so that in future I find no difficulties(errors) while using Ubuntu.

Comment: 13.04 is end of life so this is off topic. It might be a good moment for you to install 14.04. Your question also already has been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error

Answer (score 0):

Try Reparing the grub and Ubuntu system..
[What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error)

Comment: That probably won't work (see the link in comment ;-) )

Comment: and this is a possible duplicate of- <http://http://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error>

Answer (score 0):

The Boot-Repair tool might be useful for you.

It can repair most of the issues related to wrong boot sectors and so on.

Check it out on the official Ubuntu help website.

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)