# error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0

Tags: boot, grub2

After starting up my laptop - which runs Ubuntu 14.04, I got

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0
```

when I manage to boot using command line I got

```
grub>
```

when I write

```
grub> ls
```

I get

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0
```

does this mean that my hdd has gone bad?

Updates:
when I log in using bios, it seems that hdd is recognizable and does not seem to have an issue.
My question is different than other posted question such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error), in such way that `grub ls` does not output anything!

Comment: @charlesbridge please see my updates...

Comment: @DavidFoerster I did what is in the link to fix grub…However, when I turn on my laptop I get grub screen right away and following charles link didn't help me much...

Comment: What was the output of Boot-Repair? Even if it didn't fix your issue, it likely contains much valuable data to contribute to a solution.