# Trouble Installing 14.04

Tags: system-installation, raid

9.10 64 Bit works just fine. No later version will install.
If I install anything newer than 9.10 I get the error:

> attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Boot Repair and all the online advice on this error have failed to work.
I'm running a 4.5 Terabyte Rocket Raid. In 4 drive RAID 5 configuration.

And as I said, 9.10 worked fine for 5 years.

I tried all the instruction on the very page you linked: [What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error)

Nothing made any difference. the "ls" command in Grub repair outputs "Unknown File System" on every partition.

I just tried 12.04 and got the same error.

All Live boot disks work fine and the install goes without errors.

Reboot...dead duck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error)

Comment: I just tried 9.10 again and it works fine. Of course I can't update it or install any programs. Sys diagnostics show no issues. In 9.10...

Comment: Can you try again with the "Try Ubuntu" option of the installation medium for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I've tried to install using the "Try Ubuntu" option many many times. It runs fine off a DVD or USB drive. It installs without errors. Then I reboot and get nothing but "Grub Repair" and all file systems are unrecognised.