# Kubuntu started freezing + Grub broken

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I've been a happy Kubuntu user for a month ago, with no problems until now. I run four operating systems (Windows 10, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Mate and Apricity OS) on one machine, which was working perfectly yesterday. Today I noticed that GRUB was slow to load.

I chose Kubuntu, and it started booting, but there was an error message on the screen which disappeared after a few seconds. Then the Kubuntu screen appeared for much longer than usual. Finally, I had the lock screen in front of me, but it didn´t let me enter my password for several minutes. After that, Kubuntu loaded in a minute, while it normally takes a few seconds.

Everything seemed OK. Skype, as always, started up. I always close it as soon as it opens, so I right clicked the skype icon in the taskbar, and attemped to close it. But everything was frozen. After a minute, it unfroze, but some seconds later, it froze again.

I decided to reboot the computer and take pictures of everything.

The error message I get when I select Kubuntu:

[image]

After the reboot, Kubuntu was freezing again. So I rebooted one more time; And now I got more error messages, but this time, before even the GRUB screen appeared:

[image]

It says:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk "hd0"
```

After that, Grub opened, but this time the interface was bigger for some reason, and there were less operating systems there.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The error indicates a mangled partition table (attempting to access an area beyond the disk extents) The question here is the root cause. My bet is a failing hard disk. I recommend that you boot from live media and [check the smart status](http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077) of your drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error)