# Unable to boot cloned Ubuntu on SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd, grubrescue, cloning

I brought a 240GB SSD and installed in my laptop using [HDD Caddy](http://www.amazon.in/CNCT-SATA-caddy-Universal-DVD-ROM/dp/B018LJGESI?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=af286b0c-0aa4-4beb-9c52-8ca8705e912c). After that I cloned my previous Ubuntu partition to new SSD partition following [MovingLinuxPartition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition) blog. After following steps I restarted laptop as suggested but ended up with Black screen with no message.

Then I followed same procedure but till step 4. I restarted laptop, this time I was able to boot into new SSD ubuntu partition. I deleted old partition from normal HDD as everything was working fine. But as soon as I again restarted system, `Grub rescue>` prompt showed up saying `attempt to read and write outside of "hd1"`. I googled it and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/397520/433087) that couldn't solve the issue.

When I ran :

`grub rescue> ls (hd1,1)/`

it gives me list of files as usual, but running:

`grub rescue> ls (hd1,1)/boot/`

gives same message `attempt to read and write outside of "hd1"`.

**Edit**

I have generated boot-info report using `boot-info` tool. Report is [here](https://paste2.org/LKIGedBn)

I am stuck here, I searched a lot but unable to find solution.

Please help me.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Have you tried running `grub-install /dev/sdX`  on your new drive (replacing X with the appropriate device letter)?

Comment: yes, even used with `--boot-directory` and `--root-directory` also.

Comment: @oldfred I have added report in the question, please check.

Comment: You have duplicate UUIDs, which is not allowed. Grub then is confused on which partition to use, see lines 160 in report on sda6 and sdb1. Do not install grub to partitions, just MBR of drive. See tune2fs or uuidgen. Which Ubuntu do you want to boot now? Do you want Windows boot loader on sda and Ubuntu/grub bootloader on sdb? You probably can boot both installs, but one with new UUID will need grub & fstab updated with new UUID.

Comment: @oldfred I want to boot into SSD ubuntu and Windows. Actually i have done that too. I changed UUID and edited /etc/fstab file and then installed grub stilll had same problem.  Right now i have deleted sda6 partition, how can i repair boot for sdb1.

Comment: Boot-Repairs advanced options, should let you choose an install and choose which drive to install boot loader into. So choose install in sdb1 and choose sdb for grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Comment: @oldfred I did that too, I tried every single blog in could find. But the problem was something else. Inserting SSD in place of internal HDD solve the issue. Very funny :) .

Answer (score 0):

Even after doing fresh `Ubuntu` install on SSD didn't work.

Then I thought of swapping of Internal HHD and SSD (that i inserted into [HDD Caddy](http://www.amazon.in/CNCT-SATA-caddy-Universal-DVD-ROM/dp/B018LJGESI?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=af286b0c-0aa4-4beb-9c52-8ca8705e912c)). After swapping just a normal `boot-repair` worked perfectly.

Then I thought, May be, we can't have Ubuntu bootable in external HDD installed in HDD Caddy. But before swapping to HDDs i did a fresh install in internal HDD too that is working even with HDD Caddy. TO be sure I don't really know the exact issue on it. But what i really know is Putting SSD in internal HDD slot worked.