# Error: Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' after test multiple solutions

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, lubuntu, grubrescue

I have lubuntu 18.04 and Windows XP with boot of windows vista installed.
Then it said update is available and I updated.
Then it said you should restart.
And after restart I got this error:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk'hd0'. Entering secure mode… grub rescue>
```

And when I type ls it got this:
`(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos1)`

None of all solutions worked for me
In all forums after you set prefix and root you should enter:
`insmod normal`
But again it got me error: `attempt to read or write outside of disk'hd0'.`
Also after installing lubuntu 18.04 it got me this error but after pressing a key the error disappears.

Edit: I can't boot to any usb or cd

Comment: I would not boot your system, but boot a 'live' system (eg. Lubuntu/Ubuntu install media) and check the health of your drive (it's likely okay, but I'd do it anyway; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) then if clean I'd `fsck` (file system check) your used Lubuntu partitions.  After that is done (if errors were detected & fixed) I would boot normally and expect it to boot.  There are other reasons for the issue, but one can be logical errors on the disk fixed with `fsck`.  What other solutions have you tried?

Comment: The bigger problem is that this laptop's DVD-rom is corrupt and it doesn't support booting from usb natively and I installed using plop boot manager now I haven't any access to it. :(

Comment: You have to have either USB boot or DVD boot to fix system. Only other alternative is to remove hard drive and plug into another working system and repair it there, if hard drive is still ok.

Comment: @oldfred can I use grubsecure to fix it?

Comment: Example of grub rescue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error

Comment: @oldfred That solution gives me ```error: attempt to read or write outside of disk'hd0'.``` again.

Comment: Then you probably need to chroot into system from a working system and reinstall grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/935008/boot-error-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-after-update