# ubuntu 14.04 error "attempt to read outside of disk 'hd0'"

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I followed the top post off of this question [What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error) . After typing these two steps after finding
filetype ext 2 or something similar on hd0,msdos5

grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos5)

grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub

I was unable to do anything else. 
After restarting I now get "Reboot and select proper boot device".
From here I can see in my BIOS that my hard drive is not being detected. I tried unplugging and replugging the cables and same response on boot "Reboot and select proper boot device".
I've launched Ubuntu on a live USB and tried to install boot repair but get no option to repair boot. Here is my paste bin http://paste.ubuntu.com/25853215/

From this point I have no idea what to do other than buy a new hardrive. I have a 2 terrabyte seagate drive that I was dual booting ubuntu and windows on. My machine crashed when I was playing a game on windows.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your hard drive is not recognized, is it working ? Or are you looking at hard drive failure ? All I see in your boot-repair output is your flash drive with the live image. Try fdisk, testdisk, etc. Identify hardware.

Comment: When using fdisk and testdisk, neither show that I have a hard drive connected and only show the USB memory. using dmidecode -q , I saw multiple sections of Memory Device { Size: No Module Installed, Type: Unknown, Data Width: 64 bits} (those were just some of the key value pairs listed under multiple sections of Memory Device) I guess I'm looking at hard drive failure? It was working fine playing Overwatch and then froze up on me. I don't really have any data I need saved, but I have no other computer to check and see if the hard drive has failed

Comment: Sounds like hard drive failure. The only other possibility would be a loose connection. Open the box, check the connections, and see if you "bios" detects the drive. If not, l think you need to look for a replacement drive.

Comment: Thanks for your time, It's just weird because I was originally in the grub rescue prompt before I used those two commands. That leads me to believe that it was accessing the partition with Ubuntu on it because that's the partition GRUB was installed on.

Comment: It is strange, hard to say unless you can access the drive for diagnostics .

Comment: I had to take it to get it diagnostic tested and you were correct it was a faulty drive. Thanks for helping me trouble shoot that

Comment: You are welcome, I am sorry your drive failed. I have seen them fail more than once and when they do they can go fast with little or no warning.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by changing the partition size to 100gb. 120gb is the max. This is for older pcs.