# Not able to grub rescue with error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: boot, grub2

I am fairly new to linux. Unfortunately, after 3 days of installations, software updates, setup the system died on its own with no warning. I have no energy to set everything up again. It is a work computer and my work is getting delayed. It ended up in grub more. I used live CD to reinstall GRUB and do whatever everyone else suggested on forums. Eventually, nothing works with "error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' "  error. When I type the following:
ls (hd0,1)
I see my linux partition and files. I can even browse further ls(hd0,1)/home etc. However ls(hd0,1)/boot results in "error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' ".  Cannot do insmod normal etc with the same error. could someone please help? Nothing on forums helped me so far.

Comment: This is a very old error that only happens in very old hardware and this is what you probably need: https://askubuntu.com/a/398808/692175 . Additional info: It's a BIOS problem/limitation that may or may not have been corrected in some BIOS update (check at the manufacturer's website).

Comment: Thanks so much. I did this. I reinstalled ubuntu following these steps.. so far seems stable. lets see.

Comment: I was having these same issues.  Turns out my power supply was bad.  It started as a every once in a while thing, and then it got worse.  It got to the point of my drive being detected every other reboot.  Replaced the power supply and now it is rock solid stable.