# Boot errors, slow system

Tags: 14.04

So my Asus laptop has had a few problems and I'm looking forward to buying something new, but until then, I need to fix another issue. Yesterday, Ubuntu crashed, and when I try to boot it now i get:
Error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0
Press any key to continue...
After this, I'm sometimes asked to do a manual fsck, which I do, and after exiting initframes it boots to the login screen, but it takes some time to log in, and I can't run any programs, they just attempt to open for some time and then stop. What can I do about this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you use `gparted` or another tool to modify the sizes, or move partitions?  If you have, you've moved the 'grub 1.5' sector to beyond the capacity of your bios/hardware.   You may get some clues from https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error   If I was you I'd check that condition of your drive anyway as a first step using `smartctl` or whatever you favorite tool for this is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your disk is broken ... take a backup of any important data, buy a new disk, or a new computer, if you have planed to replace it anyway.