# Ubuntu won't boot - error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: boot

so the other day I unplugged my PC running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (it was completely shut down when I plugged it out), and a week later, I plugged it back in and since then I can't boot it with that issue:

```
"error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'"
"Entering rescue mode..."
"grub rescue>"
```

The PC has a single 120GB SSD installed, single partition, and I can't really remember what partition type it is.

```
PC:
Core2Quad Q8200 2.33GHz
6GB DDR2 RAM
Asus P5K-SE motherboard
((some low spec AMD gpu with 1GB of memory))
Crucial 120GB SSD
```

Just don't tell me I have to reinstall Ubuntu, for the 3rd time now.

EDIT:
turns out it was a faulty... SATA cable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/398808/197910