# Error message after installing ubuntu 20.04 atempt to read or write outside of disk hd0 while starting the computer

Tags: grub2, reboot, grubrescue

It shows the error

> attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
> Entering rescue mode
> Grub rescue>

Comment: The answers in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/397485/1222991) might give you something to work with.

Comment: We don't know what OS & release you're talking about, but I'd stop trying to boot it, boot *live* media & `fsck` your partition(s).  If errors are detected they will be corrected and you'll be able to boot next time normally.  *edit:  your title does say 20.04 so you gave some of that detail, details in title should be repeated in description as title is not always viewable when reading question text with some devices/browser/setups*