# Ubuntu boot error: attempt to read or write outside of disk `hd0`. Press any key to continue. Pressing any key doesn’t work

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I get the following error when I boot my laptop

`error: attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0. Press any key to continue...`

Nothing happens when I press any key. So I am unable to apply any existing solutions. I cannot get past the above error screen.

During the boot, I press and hold the shift key to enter the grub menu. Here I go to advance options and try to boot in recovery mode. But then I get an error saying manual fsck required. After I perform run `fsck /dev/sda1` I get an error
“warning filesystem still has errors”. I am not sure how to fix this.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Given the lack of actionable detail, LMGTFY ⇢ [click here](https://askubuntu.com/a/397520/1222991)

Comment: My keyboard is also missing the "any" key. :) Try Boot-Repair and post report. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This happened to me when I had a bad power supply.  I can't remember fully but either the -12V or -5V rail was not working.  Check your hardware to make sure everything is working.

Comment: @oldfred I am unable to get past the above error screen. Can’t get to the terminal

Comment: Is sda1 your only ext4 partition? From live installer run e2fsck on all ext4 partitions. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 But if UEFI install, first partition is normally an ESP, which must be FAT32 which would require dosfsck.