# install of ubuntu hd0 beyond read write

Tags: boot, grub2

I have tried a lot of solutions posted and now am submitting to community. Here is a pastebin of the error: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pm7mrrxtCC/ I tried the boot repair the grub rescue, I started to try to reinstall grub, but I didn't really know the best way. It seems like it is trying to load all the boot things at the end and beyond the drive.

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: MGA G200eW WPCM450 from Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 6.6.0(6.6) from Dell Inc.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 5.47 TiB, 5997921828864 bytes, 11714691072 sectors
Disk sdb: 14.33 GiB, 15382609920 bytes, 30044160 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x1693364d
      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *          0  6599743  6599744  3.2G  0 Empty
sdb2       5930192  5938191     8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb3       6602752 30044159 23441408 11.2G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:5998GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:DELL PERC 6/i:;
sdb:15.4GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:SanDisk Cruzer Glide:;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
sdb    iso9660  2022-02-23-09-09-33-00                                                    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2022-02-23-09-09-33-00               1693364d-01                          Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS amd64 
├─sdb2 vfat     54C5-9C6C                            1693364d-02                                                   
└─sdb3 ext4     2e89d78e-ff9a-4cef-bb94-4dc4dbd19a04 1693364d-03                          writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                              Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-20.4/crash] 10.3G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-20.4/log]   10.3G   0% /var/log
/dev/sdb1                                                         0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-20.4/crash] ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-20.4/log]   ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdb

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  04 c8 53 00 00 00 00 00  4d 36 93 16 00 00 80 00  |..S.....M6......|
000001c0  01 00 00 c9 e0 fc 00 00  00 00 40 b4 64 00 00 fe  |..........@.d...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff d0 7c  5a 00 40 1f 00 00 00 00  |.......|Z.@.....|
000001e0  66 9b 83 29 db 4e 00 c0  64 00 00 b0 65 01 00 00  |f..).N..d...e...|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

Comment: You mention "*beyond the drive*" which reminds of error(s) you get if your drive is failing, OR you're using media that contains errors & is faulty (*did you verify it? you've provided no specific details so we can't rule out or assume anything*).  Either way I'd check your drive health & the box/system it was run on (if *live* media did verify scans complete successfully; as you've mentioned an error that may imply they didn't)

Comment: Tried all of these https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error I believe it to be a grub error. Drives less than 3 mths old worked fine on raid 5 changed to raid 0 and tried install said the error and puts me in the rescue grub no matter what I do. Yes scans complete no errors. Ubuntu site says this occurs as a security feature if ubuntu reads beyond first 100 gigs. So I tried switching to uefi as well. Same thing. Then switched back

Comment: We've no OS/product/release details; so we'd only be guessing. Did you check the drive SMART health?  In my experience loads of drives fail in the warranty period; when you have the chance to do something about it (*ie. replacement if you're willing to sign rights away to your data on dead drive*)

Comment: It is Ubuntu 22.04 switched up from 20.04  on an r610 dell Linux machine I will try a smart drive check on livecd Ubuntu install usb

Comment: went into drive right clicked drive to check, the smart drive check will not highlight, format and other options say cannot unmount this is probably cause I am in the installation

Comment: Check disk at installation has no errors

Comment: If drive was RAID, it may still have RAID meta data on it. Do not use if you have data not backed up. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411206/how-to-wipe-md-raid-meta

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by using advanced partitioning and partitioning myself on the "something other menu" in the install