# error: attemp to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' Entering rescue mode... grub rescure>

Tags: boot

I got
error: attemp to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescure>
when i try to boot ubuntu for external HDD on hp elitebook 8460p
how can i sorve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error)

Comment: Hi - what Ubuntu version is involved here? Was Ubuntu installed using that PC onto the external drive, or was it installed using a different PC and then that external drive was connected to your current one?