# Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: boot, 14.04, bootloader, grubrescue

I installed 14.04 on my new 3 TB disk. After restart the system responded with

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

When I booted with Live CD the result of `sudo parted -l` is the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l 
Model: ATA WDC WD3001FAEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  2984GB  2983GB  ext4
 3      2984GB  3001GB  17.1GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Duplicate of [Booting Ubuntu Failure : error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229715/booting-ubuntu-failure-error-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0)

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and "fixed" it by reinstalling ubuntu with the LVM option.

Comment: Can you please include more details to this answer like how to install Ubuntu with the LVM option.

Comment: When you install ubuntu there is a dialog which specifically asks you if you want to "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation" which you either check or not. It's a decission you have to take in any case when you install Ubuntu. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall