# Not able to install any linux distro

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, kernel, graphics

I messed up with my `ubuntu 15.10`. I was trying to install `gnome-desktop-environment` by running the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment`, but I closed the process in between.
After than my `ubuntu` didn't start(displayed a black terminal like `grub` screen in which when I entered the command boot, it showed `load the kernel first` error) . So I decided to remove it.

I was able to completely remove the ubuntu by `fixmbr` command using recovery drive and deleted the `ubuntu` folder in the boot directory in `efi` partition . I removed all the ubuntu partitions as well.

But still I am not able to do a fresh installation of any linux distro. When I try to load the distro from live CD,before loading `ACPI PCC Probe failed` Error is displayed and the loading screen never ends and the caps lock starts blinking infinitely.

I also tried booting using `nomodeset` but then it displayed the following error `blk update request : I/O error , dev sda ,sector xxxxxx`
I guess something is wrong with my graphics setting as I interrupted that gnome-environment installation process.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but your ACPI PCC error is normal, it's informational only, most 3.19 and newer kernels display it, it's normal and not a real error indication.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105030/what-is-happening-i-o-error-dev-sda-sector-545868115  Your harddrive is broken ...

Comment: Can you provide more info about your system..it's seems to be bit old(as you are using live CD)...may be your hard drive is broken...you can try ubuntu rather than installing if you have live usb and your computer can boot via that.

Comment: Sorry I mentioned live CD , I'm using live USB , and even try Ubuntu does not work , it just gets stuck on the loading screen.