# Unable to mount external HDD to UBUNTU 17?

Tags: hard-drive, 17.04, external-hdd

I am trying to mount my external hdd on UBUNTU 17.04 but it is showing following errors.

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 964419583 964417536 459.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       964421630 976771071  12349442   5.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       964421632 976771071  12349440   5.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
inspire@inspire-Insp:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt 

Cmount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

    inspire@inspire-Insp:~$ dmesg | tail
[  408.306648] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
[  408.306649] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 38 00
[  408.309911] scsi host6: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[  408.402592] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  408.556439] scsi host6: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[  408.556796] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=0x0e
[  408.556803] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  408.556807] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  408.556813] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 38 00
[  408.556817] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 64
```

Is my HDD dead ? What is the possible conclusion of above error ?

Comment: Possibly related to disk degradation. Consider this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/105030/what-is-happening-i-o-error-dev-sda-sector-545868115

Comment: @ThePizzaOverlord I did what is mentioned in the above post but my hdd is not recognizable by the command sudo fdisk -l